# How to make header fixed using AngularDart AppLayout Component?

Tags: angular, angular-dart, angular-components

Basead on [Dart AppLayout Example](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#AppLayout), I would like to know how to make header fixed (Toolbar) without content itens overlay on header.

To make header fixed, I used this CSS:

```
material-content material-drawer {
    position: fixed;
}

material-content header {
    position: fixed;
}
```

But the another content elements are overlay on the header. See the image, where a `<material-list-item>` from `<material-list>` is over the header.

What the better way to make the header fixed? How could this overlap be avoided?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We handle this with css styling. Set the `z-index` of the header to be greater than that of it's sibling elements.